# python Spark job in Oozie using spark action

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, pyspark, hortonworks-data-platform

I have been trying to run a python script in spark(1.3.1.2.3) and I' am using oozie to schedule the spark job. I have a 3 node cluster running HDP 2.3 installed using Ambari 2.1.1.

I'm running into the following error when executing the job..

```
>>> Invoking Main class now >>>

Fetching child yarn jobs
tag id : oozie-9d5f396daac34b4a41fed946fac0472
Child yarn jobs are found - 
Spark Action Main class        : org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit

Oozie Spark action configuration
=================================================================

                    --master
                    yarn-client
                    --deploy-mode
                    client
                    --name
                    boxplot outlier
                    --class
                    /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/AnalyticsJar/boxplot_outlier.py
                    --executor-memory
                    1G
                    --driver-memory
                    1G
                    --executor-cores
                    4
                    --num-executors
                    2
                    --conf
                    spark.yarn.queue=default
                    --verbose
                    /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/AnalyticsJar/boxplot_outlier.py

=================================================================

>>> Invoking Spark class now >>>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/AnalyticsJar/boxplot_outlier.py", line 129, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/AnalyticsJar/boxplot_outlier.py", line 60, in main
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
  File "/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1314/spark-core_2.10-1.1.0.jar/pyspark/context.py", line 107, in __init__
  File "/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1314/spark-core_2.10-1.1.0.jar/pyspark/context.py", line 155, in _do_init
  File "/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1314/spark-core_2.10-1.1.0.jar/pyspark/context.py", line 201, in _initialize_context
  File "/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1314/spark-core_2.10-1.1.0.jar/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 701, in __call__
  File "/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/1314/spark-core_2.10-1.1.0.jar/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.FilterRegistration"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:895)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:665)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:758)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:98)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.createServletHandler(JettyUtils.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.createServletHandler(JettyUtils.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.attachPage(WebUI.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI$$anonfun$attachTab$1.apply(WebUI.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI$$anonfun$attachTab$1.apply(WebUI.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.attachTab(WebUI.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.initialize(SparkUI.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.<init>(SparkUI.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.<init>(SparkUI.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Intercepting System.exit(1)

<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<
```

Here is my workflow.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.4' name='sparkjob'>
    <start to='spark-process' />
    <action name='spark-process'>
        <spark xmlns='uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1'>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>oozie.launcher.mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>launcher2</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>oozie.service.SparkConfigurationService.spark.configurations</name>
                <value>spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://node1.analytics.tardis:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory,spark.yarn.historyServer.address=http://node1.analytics.tardis:18088,spark.eventLog.enabled=true</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <master>yarn-client</master>
        <mode>client</mode>
        <name>boxplot outlier</name>
        <class>/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/AnalyticsJar/boxplot_outlier.py</class>
        <jar>/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/AnalyticsJar/boxplot_outlier.py</jar>
        <spark-opts>--executor-memory 1G --driver-memory 1G --executor-cores 4 --num-executors 2 --conf spark.yarn.queue=default</spark-opts>
        </spark>
        <ok to='end'/>
        <error to='spark-fail'/>
    </action>
    <kill name='spark-fail'>
        <message>Spark job failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>

    <end name='end' />
</workflow-app>
```

From an initial search it seems that the error pops up because of conflicting dependencies in packaging a jar file that contains code for running the spark job. The python script boxplot_outlier.py does not import any dependency that might cause such a conflict.

In need of some guidance! Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I checked the Classpath elements of the Oozie Java/Map-Reduce/Pig action launcher-job configuration and it includes the following two jars

```
/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/ambari-qa/appcache/application_1441804290161_0903/container_e03_1441804290161_0903_01_000002/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar

/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/ambari-qa/appcache/application_1441804290161_0903/container_e03_1441804290161_0903_01_000002/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar
```

From the discussions in [SPARK-1693](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1693) it seems that these two jars may cause this kind of a dependency conflict. The issue though has been stated as resolved in version 1.1.0 itself. There maybe an issue with the dependencies of hadoop 2.7 or there might be some configuration I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it. Turns out removing the **javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar** from the oozie sharelib spark directory in hdfs mitigates the issue. I'm not sure whether this is the right way to tackle the issue and if this is a configuration issue with the HDP 2.3.0 distribution. Will report it to the HDP guys for further investigation.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing this same issue on Cloudera CDH 5.5.2 as well.
I couldn't find any reference to this being a known issue though.
And deleting from sharelib seems like a big hack.

To test this theory, removed javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar from sharelib and did a sharelibupdate (otherwise Oozie was saying file is missing), added javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar to my own custom oozie.libpath (can be in sharelib as well but didn't want to do that) and issue went away. There must be another way.

Nevertheless sharing here as well in case helpful.